# Navigate to Button Click Event in Lens Application for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Upon pressing the Lens tile icon for my application within the default camera application on Windows Phone, I would like to navigate to my application. I have this working, although I am using the CameraCaptureTask to take photos and then I save and display them within my MainPage. I am calling CameraCaptureTask on a click event, so my question is how might I access this click event when I select the Application Tile in the Lens picker?

App.xaml.cs

```
private void InitializePhoneApplication()
    {
        if (phoneApplicationInitialized)
            return;

        // Create the frame but don't set it as RootVisual yet; this allows the splash
        // screen to remain active until the application is ready to render.
        //RootFrame = new PhoneApplicationFrame();
        RootFrame = new TransitionFrame();
        RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

        // Assign the lens example URI-mapper class to the application frame.
        RootFrame.UriMapper = new LensUriMapper();

        // Handle navigation failures
        RootFrame.NavigationFailed += RootFrame_NavigationFailed;

        // Handle reset requests for clearing the backstack
        RootFrame.Navigated += CheckForResetNavigation;

        // Ensure we don't initialize again
        phoneApplicationInitialized = true;
    }
```

LensUriMapper.cs

```
class LensUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    private string tempUri;

    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        tempUri = uri.ToString();

        // Look for a URI from the lens picker.
        if (tempUri.Contains("ViewfinderLaunch"))
        {
            // Launch as a lens, launch viewfinder screen.
            //return new Uri("/Views/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
            return new Uri("/Views/MainPage.xaml?Viewfinder=1", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        }

        // Otherwise perform normal launch.
        return uri;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Viewfinder"))
    {
        newButton_Click(null, null);
    }
}

void newButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        _cameraTask.Show();
    }
```

In addition, how might I navigate directly back to the default camera application upon the back key press as stated in MSDN's Lens application guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a parameter to the ViewfinderLaunch uri:

```
return new Uri("/Views/MainPage.xaml?Viewfinder=1", UriKind.Relative);
```

Next you have to override the "OnNavigatedTo" method of your MainPage to check if Viewfinder parameter is setted:

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("Viewfinder"))
{
    newButton_Click(null, null);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but for some reason the debugger is breaking without any error messages. I edited my code above to reflect my changes.

Comment: I believe it is breaking when or after setting `return new Uri("/Views/MainPage.xaml?Viewfinder=1", UriKind.Relative);`